# $A\otimes B\cong A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I am struggling for quite a while now with tensor products, since I have limeted time to learn to understand them. Now on several occasions I have read that we have $A\otimes_KK\cong A$ for $A$ an $K$-algebras. I convinced myself of this by "showing" the following function is an isomorphism:

> \begin{align}f:A\otimes_KK&\to A\\a\otimes_Kk&\mapsto a\end{align}
>   Surjectivity: obvious
>
> Injectivity: $\ker(f)=\{a\otimes_Kk\in A\otimes_KK\mid f(a\otimes_Kb)=a=0\}=\{0\otimes_Kk\mid 0\in A, k\in K\}=\{0\}$ hence $f$ is injective.

I suspect something is terribly wrong with this proof, because we can do the same thing if we replace $K$ by any $K$-algebra $B$. In wich case $A\otimes B\cong A$, wich doesn't appear right...

My question is: What would be the correct way to show relations like this? (And implicitly: what am I not getting when using tensor products?)

Comment: Your map is not k-linear. The map should take $a\otimes k$ to $ak$.

Comment: Also, your map is obviously not injective since $a \otimes 1$ and $a \otimes 2$ have the same image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of your errors is that you think every element of a tensor product $A\otimes_K B$ is an elementary tensor $a\otimes b$. I say this because from the way you are defining $f$ and trying to compute the kernel it seems you think every tensor is elementary. Elements of a tensor product are *sums* of elementary tensors $a_1\otimes b_1 + \cdots + a_r \otimes b_r$. Now it *is* true in $A \otimes_K K$ that all tensors are elementary, but it is not true in general tensor products. In particular, to show a linear map out of a tensor product is zero it is insufficient in general to show the only *elementary* tensor that goes to $0$ is the zero tensor. For example, there is an $\mathbf R$-linear map $\mathbf C \otimes_{\mathbf R} \mathbf C \rightarrow \mathbf C$ by $z \otimes w \mapsto zw$ on *elementary* tensors and the only elementary tensor that goes to $0$ is $0 \otimes 0$ (do you understand that $z \otimes 0 = 0 \otimes w = 0 \otimes 0$ in this tensor product?), but lots of non-elementary tensors also go to $0$ so the map is not injective. For instance, $1\otimes i - i \otimes 1$ is mapped to $0$ and $1\otimes i - i \otimes 1$ is not elementary in $\mathbf C \otimes_{\mathbf R} \mathbf C$. Being able to prove that tensor is not elementary is one indicator that you can work properly with tensors.

Comment: I do know that not every element of a tensor product is an elementary tensor. However I am not sufficiently comfortable around tensors to constantly remind myself of this. So you are right to say I assumed as much in my "proof". Anyway I would like to thank you for this very adequate example.

Comment: You might want to look at the second full paragraph on page 11, the questions on page 12, and Remark 4.16 of http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf. Nobody ever writes down a formula for a map out of a tensor product by writing down its value on *all* tensors, but only on the elementary tensors. This is unlike other algebraic structures where formulas for homomorphisms might be defined on all elements of the domain. So this habit can tend to blind the newcomer to the fact that most tensors are *not* elementary tensors. They do span it, though (but not as a basis).

Comment: Thank you very much for going the "extra mile" and sharing this text on tensor products. My first impression of it is really positive and I will cerainly look in to it.

Answer (score 4):

This map is actually not even well defined. This is because $f(a \otimes 2) = a$, but $f(2a \otimes 1) = 2a$, even though $a \otimes 2 = 2a \otimes 1$ in $A \otimes_K K$. The correct map is $a \otimes k \mapsto ka$.

Comment: Could you give me an idea of what goes wrong if neither of the domain vector spaces is $K$ itself? (see also JoeyBF's answer)

Comment: Well what would $b \cdot a$ mean if $b \in B$ and $a \in A$ are both vector spaces?

Answer (score 2):

Your isomorphism should be
\begin{align}
f: A \otimes_K K& \to A\\
a \otimes_K k& \mapsto k \cdot a
\end{align}
This is a well-defined isomorphism and is $K$-linear, which your function wasn't. Because the scalar multiplication is only defined for scalars, this isomorphism can only be defined when one of the domain vector spaces is $K$ itself.

Comment: Could you give me an idea of what goes wrong if neither of the domain vector spaces is $K$ itself?

Comment: @gebruiker Well if the linear map has no $k \in K$ as an input, then there is no way to use scalar multiplication and give an element of $A$. This is because there is in general no natural way to define multiplication of two vectors, when neither is a scalar. Simply put, things don't just go wrong, the map simply becomes indefinable.

Comment: @JoeyBF: That is not quite true. Since the setting is $K$-algebras, for any $K$-algebra $A$ there is a map $A\otimes_K A\rightarrow A$ given by $a\otimes a' \mapsto aa'$ on elementary tensors. This is surjective if $A$ has a multiplicative identity, since we can already get all elements of $A$ in the image using just elementary tensors. But it will never be injective if $\dim_K(A) > 1$ since the tensor product's dimension is greater than the dimension of $A$ itself, whether or not there is a multiplicative identity in $A$.

Comment: @gebruiker: See the example in my answer of $\mathbf C \otimes_{\mathbf R} \mathbf C \rightarrow \mathbf C$ for an example of a specific nonzero (non-elementary) tensor mapping to $0$. Think about bases over $K$ to build similar examples in the general case of $K$-algebras.

Comment: @KCd Ah yes, my bad. I forgot that we were working with $K$-algebras. Nice catch.